# Как отправлять файлы на сервер при помощи ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Здравствуйте.
Работаю с ExtJS 3.1. Необходимо реализовать загрузку файлов на сервер. Нашел пример, который все утверждают, что работает (на многих сайтах он один и тот же), но у меня категорически не хочет отправлять на сервер. Привожу код:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

Ext.QuickTips.init();

var msg = function(title, msg){
    Ext.Msg.show({
                title: title,
                msg: msg,
                minWidth: 200,
                modal: true,
                icon: Ext.Msg.INFO,
                buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
            });
};

var fp = new Ext.FormPanel({
            renderTo: 'fi-form',
            id: 'forma',
            fileUpload: true,
            width: 500,
            frame: true,
            title: 'File Upload Form',
            autoHeight: true,
            bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;',
            labelWidth: 50,
            defaults: {
                anchor: '95%',
                allowBlank: false,
                msgTarget: 'side'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
                id: 'form-file',
                emptyText: 'Select a File to import',
                fieldLabel: 'File',
                name: 'file',
                buttonCfg: {
                    text: 'Открыть'
                    //iconCls: 'upload-icon'
                }
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'mame',
                id: 'fff'
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Upload',
                handler: function(){
                    if(fp.getForm().isValid()){
                     fp.getForm().submit({
                     url: 'hello.htm',
                     waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
                     success: function(fp, o){
                     msg('Success', 'Processed file on the server');
                     }
                     });
                     }

                }
            },{
                text: 'Reset',
                handler: function(){
                    fp.getForm().reset();
                }
            }]
        }).show();
```

});

Если есть какой-нибудь способ полегче то, пожалуйста, напишите. Или может кто знает, что *тут* не так.

Comment: Так почему нельзя просто сделать форму с файлов и отправлять её? Куда уж проще. Вообще, если вы не знаете, что делает этот код или не понимаете его до конца, то какого чёрта пытаетесь использовать?

Comment: Потому что надо обязательно при помощи ExtJS 3.1. Я продолжаю чужой проект. Его нужно дополнить новым окном загрузки файлов. Т.е. простой HTML-код тут не катит.

Comment: Когда анализировал, то получается, что он вообще ничего не отправляет на сервер. А если ставить "fileUpload: false", то отправляет только текстовое поле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь ошибки никакой нет. Я просто на сервере неправильно принимал данные.

Comment: Вы ведь сказали, что данные не передаются.. подразумевалось, что вы хоть как-то проверили это..

Comment: Угу, проверил. Я рассчитывал, что файл, который я отправляю, будет в параметрах HttpServletRequest. Потом я где-то откопал пример, где показано, что надо так:  
InputStream is = request.getInputStream();  
Вот в инпут стриме и оказался отправляемый мною файл.

Answer (score -1):

> xtype: 'filefield'

[пример](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/file-upload.js)

Comment: Такого типа не существует. ПО крайней мере в 3.1. Быть может, Вы не указали, какой плагин надо подключать?

Comment: Мне нельзя перейти на 4 Ext. Когда я пытался заменить библиотеки, произошло очень много ужасностей. Проект довольно массивный. И все перелопачивать - это ужасно. Я ограничен только установленной версией. Я так понял, что программа, написанная на версии 3.1, практически не совместима, если ее поставить на версию 4.